# Rails 4 - Add existing association in nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I have 3 models:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blocks
  has_many :topics, :through => :blocks, dependent: :destroy

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blocks
  has_many :resources, :through => :blocks, :class_name => 'Resource', dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resources
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blocks, :allow_destroy => true

class Block < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :topic
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

My routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :topics do
    resources :resources do
      post :link
      delete :unlink
```

Everything works fine except that I'd like to have in the "Add resource" a way to select an existing resource (in a drop down) in addition to create a new one (which works fine).

So, I'd like a drop down showing all the resources, then adding the one I selected to the Block model. In other words, I need to only create the association between the topic and the ressource (via the  Block model).

I'm able to do it when I have all a multi-select but I'm banging my head to have it available with one resource only (adding it on the ones already selected).

Am I clear? :/

Thanks!
- Vincent

Answer (score 0):

If you got a complicated logic like this, it's better to use something
like ["Form Objects"](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+form+object&oq=rails+form+object&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6339j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) to save multiple models and relations between
them. I.e. move saving logic outside of both models.

`access_nested_attributes_for` should be used only for very very simple
cases (like most of Rails's magical features)